# ITextPdf 7.1.13 Library to create a report for a project using C# ASP NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, canvas, itext7

I am using ITextPdf 7.1.13 Library to create a report for a project using C# ASP NET.

The problem is that the pdf generated it's fine on my pc.

However, when I save my project it as website on the remote server generate this error.

> CS1061: 'PdfCanvas' does not contain a definition for 'AddXObjectAt'
> and no accessible extension method 'AddXObjectAt' accepting a first
> argument of type 'PdfCanvas' could be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?)

If comment this line

```
pdfCanvas.AddXObjectAt(placeholder, x + space, y - descent);
```

the pdf it's generated fine but without total of pages on pdf file.

Below are images of the problem and my code.

[image]

*code-behind*

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using iText.IO.Image;
using iText.Kernel.Colors;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Layout;
using iText.Layout.Borders;
using iText.Layout.Element;
using iText.Layout.Properties;
using Image = iText.Layout.Element.Image;
using Table = iText.Layout.Element.Table;
using System.Data;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Action;
using iText.Kernel.Font;
using iText.IO.Font.Constants;
using iText.Kernel.Geom;
using iText.Kernel.Events;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas;
using Rectangle = iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle;
using iText.Layout.Renderer;
using iText.Layout.Layout;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Xobject;

private class TableFooterEventHandler : IEventHandler
{
    private Table table;

    public TableFooterEventHandler(Table table)
    {
        this.table = table;
    }

    public void HandleEvent(Event currentEvent)
    {
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent)currentEvent;
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = docEvent.GetDocument();
        PdfPage page = docEvent.GetPage();

        int pageNumber = pdfDoc.GetPageNumber(page);
        Rectangle pageSize = page.GetPageSize();

        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page.NewContentStreamBefore(), page.GetResources(), pdfDoc);
        new Canvas(canvas, new Rectangle(36, 20, page.GetPageSize().GetWidth() - 72, 50))
            .Add(table)
            .Close();
    }

}

protected class Footer : IEventHandler
{
    protected PdfFormXObject placeholder;
    protected float side = 20;
    protected float x = 300;
    protected float y = 25;
    protected float space = 4.5f;
    protected float descent = 3;

    public Footer()
    {
        placeholder = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(0, 0, side, side));
    }

    public virtual void HandleEvent(Event @event)
    {
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent)@event;
        PdfDocument pdf = docEvent.GetDocument();
        PdfPage page = docEvent.GetPage();
        int pageNumber = pdf.GetPageNumber(page);
        Rectangle pageSize = page.GetPageSize();

        // Creates drawing canvas
        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pageSize);
        canvas.SetFontSize(10);


        Paragraph p = new Paragraph()
            .Add("Page ")
            .Add(pageNumber.ToString())
            .Add(" of");

        canvas.ShowTextAligned(p, x, y, TextAlignment.RIGHT);
        canvas.Close();

        // Create placeholder object to write number of pages
        pdfCanvas.AddXObjectAt(placeholder, x + space, y - descent);
        pdfCanvas.Release();


    }

    public void WriteTotal(PdfDocument pdfDoc)
    {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(placeholder, pdfDoc);
        canvas.SetFontSize(10);
        canvas.ShowTextAligned(pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages().ToString(),
            0, descent, TextAlignment.LEFT);
        canvas.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps these will help "Adding page numbers to an existing PDF":https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/adding-page-numbers-to-an-existing-pdf and "How not to merge documents": https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/how-not-to-merge-documents

Comment: That method `AddXObjectAt` is a fairly recent addition to iText. Thus, it looks like *when you save your project it as website on the remote server*, the program there is run with an older iText 7 version.